# Is it possible to use Html.RenderPartial in non-MVC ASP.Net page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to render MVC controls in non-MVC ASP.Net pages.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

`RenderPartial` is an extension method that extends the `HtmlHelper`. The `HtmlHelper`'s constructor takes a `ViewContext`.    All 3 of those are in the `System.Web.Mvc` namespace.  So, you'd have to a the very least reference the Mvc dll.  You would also need to create an HTML helper by creating the other 2 objects.  I'd be interested if you got it work, but I don't know if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

We need to reference the MVC dll into the project and also need to define similar structure like Route.config which will have default rout. Also  we would have Model, View and Controller folder, in which we should have the Views web.config as well